# Remove element from Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am doing an assignment, implementing own Binary Search Tree. The thing is, we have our own implementation of Node its parent is not directly accessible.

I have searched for answers, but I do not want to copy the solution entirely and I still don't seem to get it right, though. I miss some cases when the element is not removed.

Can you please help what am I doing wrong?

This is the remove method:

```
void remove(E elem) {
    if(elem != null){
        if (root != null && contains(elem)) {  
            removeFromSubtree(elem, root, null);  
        }
    }
}

void removeFromSubtree(E elem, Node<E> current, Node<E> parent) {

    if(elem.less(current.contents)){
        if(current.left == null) return ;
        removeFromSubtree(elem, current.left, current);
    } else if(elem.greater(current.contents)){
        if(current.right == null)return;
        removeFromSubtree(elem, current.right, current);
    } else {
        if(current.left != null && current.right != null){
            //both children
            if(parent == null){
                Node<E> n = new Node<>(null, null);
                n.left = root;
                removeFromSubtree(root.contents, n, null);
                root = n.left;
                root.setParent(null);
            }
            E min = subtreeMin(current.right);
            current.contents = min;
            removeFromSubtree(min, current.right, current);
        } else if(current.left != null){
            //left child
            if (parent == null) {
                    root = current.left;
                    current.left.setParent(null);
                    return ;
                }
            setParentChild(current, parent, current.left);
        } else if(current.right != null){
            //right child
            if (parent == null) {
                root = current.right;
                current.right.setParent(null);
                return ;
            }
            setParentChild(current, parent, current.right);
        } else {
            if (parent == null) {
                root = null;
                return ;
            }
            setParentChild(current, parent, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Nodes use generic interface

```
class Node<E extends DSAComparable<E>>
```

which has just methods for comparation. It looks like this

```
interface DSAComparable<E extends DSAComparable<E>> {
    boolean less(E other); 
    boolean greater(E other);
    boolean equal(E other);
}
```

I use another methon inside remove that sets node's parent's child, depending if its left child or right child.

```
void setParentChild(Node<E> node, Node<E> parent,Node<E> value){
    if(parent!= null){
        if (parent.left == node) {
            parent.left = value;
        } else {
            parent.right = value;
        }
        if(value!= null) value.setParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Method subtreeMin(Node node) finds the smallest value in a subtree (the most left one)

Comment: What do you need exactly? Most of the code you report calls methods that are not from the JDK. Without any additional details will be nearly impossible to help

Comment: There are some cases, when the element is not removed when it should. I dont know which conditions I have not included. I covered the cases both childen null, either child null, and no child null, plus cases when removing root. And I still don't get it right. So my question is, is there any condition I did not includ?

Comment: You have to provide the implementation of the other methods. E.g., what do you do with `elem.less()`?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope it will help.

Comment: It might be helpful to include an `else` in `if (root != null && contains(elem))`.  You can then break within that else to examine the state of things if there's a value which is consistently not removed.  My hunch is that contains isn't returning what you're expecting all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding your code is not so easy, since it still lacks of details.

I would refer to such an implementation of the *Binary Search Tree* that you can find online.

See for instance the one from [Algorithms, 4th Ed.](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html).